# How do I print that the type of a variable is interface {}

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("doing typeSwitchFunc(nil):")
    typeSwitchFunc(nil)

    fmt.Println("\ndoing typeSwitchFunc(22):")
    typeSwitchFunc(22)

}

func typeSwitchFunc(i interface{}) {
    switch j := i.(type) {

    case nil:
        // How do I print the type of j as interface{} ? Below only gives me the information on underlying type stored in j  -- (A)
        fmt.Printf("case nil: j is type %T, j value %v, i is type %T, i value %v\n", j, j, i, i)
        fmt.Printf("case nil: j is type: %v, j value: %v, j kind: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(j), reflect.ValueOf(j), reflect.ValueOf(j).Kind())
    default:
        // How do I print the type of j as interface{} ? Below only gives me the information on underlying type stored in j -- (B)
        fmt.Printf("default: j is type %T, j value %v, i is type %T, i value %v\n", j, j, i, i)
        fmt.Printf("default: j is type: %v, j value: %v, j kind: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(j), reflect.ValueOf(j), reflect.ValueOf(j).Kind())

    }
}
```

output:

```
$ go run type-switch-minimal-example.go
doing typeSwitchFunc(nil):
case nil: j is type <nil>, j value <nil>, i is type <nil>, i value <nil>
case nil: j is type: <nil>, j value: <invalid reflect.Value>, j kind: invalid

doing typeSwitchFunc(22):
default: j is type int, j value 22, i is type int, i value 22
default: j is type: int, j value: 22, j kind: int
```

```
$ go version
go version go1.17.4 darwin/amd64
```

How do I print the type of `j` as `interface {}` ?

Comment: With reflect you can do only if you have a pointer to the-interface-i-want-to-print: https://go.dev/play/p/hkzxp7-QN5l

Comment: You can just do something like `fmt.Printf("%s", "interface{}")` if you really want such a result.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I print the type of j as interface {} ?

You can't.

Source: [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) docs:

> Regardless of the verb, if an operand is an interface value, the internal concrete value is used, not the interface itself.

Why would you be interested in spelling out "interface{}" anyway? This behavior of the `fmt` package is what allows it to work with any type right away without special magic.

In [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)'s example:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf((*interface{})(nil)).Elem())
```

the output is `interface {}` because that's the string representation of `*interface{}` element type, which is truthfully `interface {}`. But in this case you're getting there via reflection, not fmt verbs.